# Paginate combination of arrays without generating the whole combination in advance

Tags: php, arrays, pagination

I have the following loop that combines two arrays and displays the results in an ordered list:

```
$list1 = array("make","break","buy");
$list2 = array("home","car","bike");

echo "<ol>";
for($a=0; $a<3; $a++){
    for($b=0; $b<3; $b++){
        echo "<li".($list1[$a].$list2[$b])."</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ol>";
```

The actual arrays that I have include about 1500 words each, so the list is more than 2 Million combinations long.

Is there a way to display the results with pagination, without generating the entire result set in advance?
For example 500 items per page?

FYI, I don't necessarily need to display the results in an ordered list, if that's going to mess up the pagination.

Comment: *"Is there a way to display the result with pagination?"* - Have you not Google'd "php pagination"? I'll bet I could find 50 results in under 5 seconds *flat* which I won't do, that's YOUR job.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I bet he/she did... I did, and found nothing relevant about paginating _combinations of arrays_. I found that interesting.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, you don't want to answer my question then comment at all. don't waste everyone's time with your useless comments.

Comment: @matpop Thanks for your input. I did search the web, but couldn't find anything close to what I was looking for. I'll give your code a try, and will come back with feedback.

Comment: @user2171083 Your modified code won't work, because it **always** starts looping from the beginning of the arrays, instead you must be able to start from variable positions, based on the chosen limit and current page (read my answer carefully). Normally, you are supposed to extract the current `$page` (and also `$limit` if you like) from the **current http GET request parameters**, because you normally present anchors in the page to previous and next pages (this is usual pagination code that you can find on your own).

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to *be able to start looping from **any** position in the arrays*.
Of course you can use `for` loops, but I think `while` loops fit better here.

```
$length1 = count($list1);
$length2 = count($list2);

//now indexes are initialized to variable values
$a = $var1; //start position $var1 is an integer variable between 0 and ($length1 - 1)
$b = $var2; //start position $var2 is an integer variable between 0 and ($length2 - 1)

while ($a < $length1) {
    while ($b < $length2) {
        echo '<li>', $list1[$a], ' ', $list2[$b], '</li>';
        $b++;
    }
    $b = 0; //reset inner loop each time it ends
    $a++;
}
```

Next, we need a way to *stop **both** loops if the maximum number of results per page (`$limit`) is reached before the end of the combinations*.

```
$length1 = count($list1);
$length2 = count($list2);
$a = $var1;
$b = $var2;

$counter = 0;

while ($a < $length1) {
    while ($b < $length2) {
        echo '<li>', $list1[$a], ' ', $list2[$b], '</li>';

        $counter++;
        if($counter === $limit) break 2;

        $b++;
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
}
```

Finally, we must find the correct values for `$var1` and `$var2` above, based on the current `$page` (starting from page 1) and `$limit`. This is *plain arithmetics* that I won't explain here.
Putting it all together:

```
$length1 = count($list1);
$length2 = count($list2);

$offset = $limit * ($page - 1);
$a = (int)($offset / $length2);
$b = $offset % $length2;

$counter = 0;
while ($a < $length1) {
    while ($b < $length2) {
        echo '<li>', $list1[$a], ' ', $list2[$b], '</li>';
        $counter++;
        if($counter === $limit) break 2;
        $b++;
    }
    $b = 0;
    $a++;
}
```